# Divide rdd with spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have an rdd with looks like

```
[u'1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2013,52,0,4,1,0',
 u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
 u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
 u'0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2014,45,0,0,1,0']
```

Is there a way to get three separate rdds like , make a filter based on year column value ?

```
[u'1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2013,52,0,4,1,0']
```

and

```
[ u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
     u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1']
```

and

```
  [u'0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2014,45,0,0,1,0']
```

Comment: Are you sure you want 3 RDDs, or do you want a single RDD with 3 lists inside?

Comment: three separate RDDs .

Comment: Do you want something that will scale past a handful of records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `groupBy`, and assuming your original RDD has the variable name `rdd`:

```
rdd = rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x.split(",")[9])
new_rdds = [sc.parallelize(x[1]) for x in rdd.collect()]

for x in new_rdds:
    print x.collect()
```

Comment: how can I get a specific rdd wich for example year = 2013 ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a better solution than this.I learned many things working on this and wasted so much of time couldn't resist to post it.

```
In [60]: a
Out[60]: 
[u'1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2013,52,0,4,1,0',
 u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
 u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
 u'0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2014,45,0,0,1,0']
```

It's very confusing for me to work with strings so i changed them into ints.

```
In [61]: b=[map(int,elem.split(',')) for elem in a]

In [62]: b
Out[62]: 
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2013, 52, 0, 4, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2012, 49, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2012, 49, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2014, 45, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Sorted b based on year.

```
In [63]: b_s=sorted(b,key=itemgetter(-6))

In [64]: b_s
Out[64]: 
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2012, 49, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2012, 49, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2013, 52, 0, 4, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2014, 45, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Using groupby from operator module to group based on year.

```
In [65]: [list(g) for k,g in groupby(b_s,key=itemgetter(-6))]
Out[65]: 
[[[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2012, 49, 1, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2012, 49, 1, 1, 0, 1]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2013, 52, 0, 4, 1, 0]],
 [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2014, 45, 0, 0, 1, 0]]]
```